# 60Ω resistor in series with inductor with 80 Ω reactance, connected to 100V. How to calculate the impedance?

Tags: resistors, circuits

I do not have the frequency so I'm stuck. Which formula can I use to get frequency? And can I then, after getting frequency, substitute it into XL= 2πfL to get inductance or should I manipulate this formula to get frequency?

Comment: You already have what you need for impedance. You have the resistance and reactance. Where do you need the frequency?

Comment: You cannot solve for two unknown variables without additional information.

Comment: @Nedd Not clear why you think there are two unknowns.  If the OP had the inductance of the inductor it would be different, but they have the impedance of the inductor which inherently must be at a given (unstated) frequency.

Comment: Pearl, This problem is testing your understanding of the material. Especially, your mastery of the idea of reactance as orthogonal to resistance and how all works with complex numbers. You can compute reactance from frequency and the value of a capacitor or inductor. But if you are given the reactance already you don't need either the frequency or the part value.

Comment: @colintd - Yes, perhaps the complex form is all the OP really needs, (per the title question, and your answer, +1).  Though the text of the question does continue: "Which formula can I use to get frequency? ...  should I manipulate this formula to get frequency?"  If those values were even needed, (two unknowns in the formula), they cannot be found from what is given so far.

Comment: @Nedd point taken.   I've added further text to my answer that might address your comment.

Answer (score 5):

You already have all the information you need to state the series impedance, which is simply Z=60+80j.

If you have the inductance (in Henries) it would be a different matter, and you would need the frequency to calculate the resultant impedance of the inductor, but that isn't an issue here.

If you were given the inductance, then you could get the frequency from: \$f=80/(2*pi*L)\$